# Running Blender from command prompt. - Beginner

Tags: python, animation, blender

I am new to `Blender`.  I have created a simple project where I have added a text variable to it. The text I added here in `Test`. See image below.

Now, I want to call this script from the command line by to call this particular project file and pass in parameters like the text variable to display the text `james` instead of `Test`.

For example, typing the following command should give me video generated with the text james.

> > blender proj1.blend variable=james

[image]

Note: I am a beginner, and I hope I explained my question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Use python script, like

```
blender proj1.blend --python-expr "import bpy; bpy.data.curves['Text'].body = 'james'"
```

(if your text curve object called "Text")

Argument order is important - you want script to be executed after file is loaded.

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial that will guide me with the steps ? Sorry but i am a beginner.

Comment: I honestly don't know, I just happen to have a bit of experience with it. What are you interested in, is my example not clear enough or you want to learn more?

Comment: When you say use python script. Did you mean for me to add the code in a `test.py` file and then execute it. Sorry , I am still trying to understand this.

Comment: Script is already in example - `--python-expr` executes given expression, so `import bpy; bpy.data.curves['Text'].body = 'james'` is a said script.

Comment: I don't know why But, i get this error `'blender' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I have already added blender.exe to my path variable as well.

Comment: That was already part of your question, so it was assumed not to be a problem. You either specify full path (probably in quotes if it contains spaces) or add directory containing executable (not the executable itself) to `PATH` (and, probably, restart `cmd` and use `echo %PATH%` to check).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the arguments used to start blender listed in [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv), the same as if you were running a normal python script. Blender will ignore any arguments after `--`, your script can then find the `--` argument and process any options after that.

```
blender -b --python maketext.py -- James
```

Then the contents of `maketext.py` would start with -

```
import bpy
import sys

idx = sys.argv.index('--') + 1
string_to_use = sys.argv[idx]

text_data = bpy.data.curves.new('txt', 'FONT')
text_data.body = string_to_use
text_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('text', text_data)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(text_obj)
# animate and render
```